# Can only log into chat by logging into Meta

Tags: support, chat, login

Somehow I got logged out of Chat and SE in general recently. I logged back into Super User successfully using Chrome, but when I went to Root Access I was told that I need to log in to chat:

[image: ra nochat]

So I hit login, used my StackExchange ID, and got punted to... StackOverflow to 'add a login'?

[image: SO]

Well, that was weird but at least I'm logged in to chat now, right? Or not:

[image: chat nologin]

I tried again but the process repeated itself. I also tried logging in via https://stackexchange.com but that also punted me back to SO without logging me in. Same effect after deleting all related cookies and incognito mode*.

A bit of searching dug up [Unable to log in to chat.stackoverflow.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158533/unable-to-log-in-to-chat-stackoverflow-com), which seemed promising. So I went to post a query on Meta about this - I had to log in to Meta as well - and started writing.

Loading up chat now shows me as logged in! I tried this again and was able to replicate.

What gives? I recently joined an SO Team, perhaps this has something to do with it?

### tl;dr sequence

1. logged out
2. `log in` to chat using StackExchange ID
3. redirected to SO 'add a login'
4. still not logged in to chat
5. `log in` to Meta
6. chat now logged in

**Why does logging in to Chat (or StackExchange) redirect me to StackOverflow 'add a login'? And why can I log in to chat via Meta?**

---

<sup>*: I wanted to test via Firefox but ran into a different issue there ("3rd party cookies seem to be disabled" → log in manually → StackExchange OpenID "Not found") which I can create another question for.</sup>

Comment: This seems related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312664/log-in-flow-on-chat-stackexchange-com-and-stackexchange-com-b0rken

Comment: as for the 3rd party cookies: That is by design. Your browser needs to accept 3rd party cookies as [Universal Login](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260153/global-auth-is-dead-long-live-universal-login) relies on it.

Comment: @rene agreed; that looks like it's a very similar, quite possibly the same issue; missed that in initial search!

Comment: I don't ever remember disallowing 3rd party cookies and I agree they are needed; but the issue I was getting at there is SE's own OpenID dealie is giving a 'not found' page on login

Comment: Yeah, there is something broken in the login flow, probably after SO for Teams got added. This needs Adam Lear to look at but they are on leave now for another 3 weeks I believe.

Comment: In this new era of everything getting more secure and browsers trying to protect their users privacy it might as well be a silent switch to disallow 3rd party cookies.

Comment: I'm 99% sure I allow 3rd party cookies (or at least never disallowed them) and I have this same issue